# Parser Error Message: The specified cryptographic algorithm is not supported on this platform : C# in Server

Tags: c#, algorithm, asp.net-mvc-4, cryptography

Confusing with this error, **I didn't do anything in the past 1 month and this error just comes up suddenly**.

```
Parser Error Message: The specified cryptographic algorithm is not supported on this platform.
```

[image: Parser Error Message: The specified cryptographic algorithm is not supported on this platform.]

**I've tried** restarting the IIS, The OS (Windows Server 2012) and adding machine.config and there is no sunshine's coming :(

**I've googling** and lookslike no one have error like this.

Somebody could help? Thx before.

Comment: That's got to be some sort of configuration error. FWIW, Microsoft's encryption layer will sometimes spit meaningless error messages when things go awry. Good luck!

Comment: Complete shot in the dark, but are you specifying a machine key in your Web.config? If so, check the validation mode.

Comment: @500-InternalServerError thx brotha. Lookslike its coming from the update from Windows Server Patch done by our server guys. Anyway your name makes me thing that's the link I'm looking for ;)

Still trying to rollback the update

Comment: @ChrisPratt Yup, that's after the error bro.